# Forward Email as RSS

Tags: gmail, rss

I'm receiving a weekly Google Alert to my Gmail account, which I would like to post as an RSS feed so people can subscribe to this same alert as a weekly update.

Anyone know where I can forward this email for it to make the conversion to RSS?

Answer (score 6):

I personally use [Emails to RSS Forwarding](http://emails2rss.appspot.com) to read Google Alerts as RSS stream. The service provides special email address to forward emails to and builds RSS feed based on them. Here is [Guide how to setup it with Gmail](http://emails2rss.appspot.com/help/gmail-forward-setup/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way you can do it:

You can setup a free wordpress.com blog, enable 'post by email' and then setup a rule to forward the emails that you want in an RSS feed to the wordpress blog.  Then grab the RSS feed from the wordpress blog (just add a /feed to the end of the wordpress.com URL).

Comment: Same with blogger.com

Answer (score 4):

Just go back to your Google Alert account page and either change the 'Deliver to' setting to 'feed' or, if you'd prefer to keep your existing email version, simply replicate the prior settings you already had created but use a feed instead of email output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get emails via RSS using the following services:

- [Zapier](https://zapier.com/): Create new Zap with *"Gmail"* trigger app with *"New Email Matching Search"* trigger. Then add *"RSS by Zapier"* app to the Zap as the second step (*"action"*). In *"Set Up Template"* step you could customize the RSS URL. Make also sure that your emails won't be larger than 10 KB. Otherwise, Zapier won't handle them.
- Notifier (I'm the author of this service): Open [email → RSS integration page](https://notifier.in/integrations/email-to-rss), where you'd see a *@ai.notifier.in* email address. Set up your emails to be forwarded to that address. Then you can read them via RSS (no registration needed).