# Save new emails/feed items to Pocket automatically

Tags: rss, feeds, if-this-then-that, feedly, pocket

## The Situation

I've subscribed to some newsletters. These newsletters/issues come out on a weekly or daily basis. I'm able to receive most of these newsletters via Email and all via RSS. **I want to save them automatically to Pocket.**

#### Newsletters/Feed items to add

- Web Design Weekly
- Responsive Design Weekly
- CSS Weekly
- Sidebar.io
- The Pastry Box Project (only RSS)
- Musigh (only RSS)

#### 1. Pocket: direct integration into Email services/feed readers

- Google Reader and Feedly both have a button to save a new item to Pocket – but I don't see a possibility there
- Such a button doesn't exist for Email services according to the guys from Pocket ([Source](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/questions/474490-any-way-to-send-full-email-to-pocket-))

#### 2. Using IFTTT & Gmail channel

Pocket can add the **first** link it finds inside an email.

- if *new email labeled "newsletter"* then *Save Body Plain to Pocket*
- if *new email labeled "newsletter"* then *Send Body Plain as Email to `add@getpocket.com`*

#### 3. Using IFTTT & Feed channel

This requires creating a recipe for any feed.

- if *new feed item from `specified feed url`* then *Save Entry URL to Pocket*

#### Other things that might help:

- [A Feedly channel for IFTTT is in the making](https://twitter.com/feedly/statuses/320677715420262400)
- [Forwarding Emails to RSS with *Emails2RSS*](http://emails2rss.appspot.com/) (thanks to [Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-everett))
- [IFTTT: Any new attachment trigger for the Gmail channel](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/triggers/367) (again, thanks to [Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-everett))

Comment: [Emails to RSS](http://emails2rss.appspot.com/) might be helpful here. (Found on [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14589/354).) You could set filters in Gmail to send to Email2RSS address, then use IFTTT to read the new feed item and add to Pocket.

Comment: Also, IFTTT _just_ introduced the "[Any new attachment](https://ifttt.com/channels/gmail/triggers/367)" trigger to the Gmail channel, in case you can get these newsletters as PDFs or the like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After testing many different solutions (see my question above for more information), I discarded my approach to use Email. Instead I've subscribed to the RSS feeds of the newsletters and use IFTTT recipes to automatically save new feed items to Pocket.

1. Subscribe to the feed(s) via RSS
2. Create a new IFTTT recipe

   - Choose *Feed* trigger channel
   - Choose *New feed item* trigger (one could adjust this by using the trigger *New feed item matches*)
   - Enter *Feed URL*
   - Choose *Pocket* action channel
   - Choose *Save for later* action
   - Add own *Tags* (optional)
   - Add *Description* and finally create the recipe
3. Wait for new feed items and the recipe to trigger – Voilà

A nice improvement would be marking the saved items as read. If I find a solution, I'll add it here.

Just if you're interested – I've shared these recipes on IFTTT: https://ifttt.com/people/kleinfreund